# Javascript push

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to push multiple values into an array.

When I use:

```
csvData.push('data[0][index],data[1][index],data[2][index],data[3][index]');
```

it formats it corrects so that

```
csvData[0] = "data[0][index],data[1][index],data[2][index],data[3][index]"
csvData[1] = "data[0][index],data[1][index],data[2][index],data[3][index]"
etc
```

Also when it evolves into a csv, it is correct in the 4 columns.

However when I use no quotes:

```
csvData.push(data[0][index],data[1][index],data[2][index],data[3][index]);
```

I get the values I want, but it's single dimensional.

```
csvData[0] = 23
92
74
22
etc
```

instead of

```
csvData[0] = 23,92,74,22
```

How can I add values it correctly?

Comment: What do you want the value of each element of `csvData` to be? An array? A string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array and push that:

```
csvData.push( [ data[0][index],data[1][index],data[2][index],data[3][index] ] );
```

The added brackets (`[ ]`) around the list of values creates an array, and that in turn is what's pushed onto the `csvData` array.

Comment: Ahh, Added the brackets and we're good.  I tried join() and that also worked.  Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Put them inside an array and join them using **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method then push it.

```
csvData.push([data[0][index],data[1][index],data[2][index],data[3][index]].join());
```

Comment: @homersheineken : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

if you want multidimentional than use

```
csvData.push([data[0][index],data[1][index],data[2][index],data[3][index]]);
```